# Tizen Push Service : error 3052

Tags: push-notification, tizen, tizen-native-app

I try sending a notification using Tizen push messaging service.

I get this error

```
statusCode : 3052
StatusMsg : "error of application authentication failed - header: APPID, regId: 0000000000000000"
```

I can't figure out why, and I can't find this error in the documentation.

I get this error only when the regId is generated by the Tizen Developer Device (os version 2.1). It works fine with the emulator.

On client-side, we used a native application based on the example 'PushClient'.

cf : https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.tizen.native.appprogramming%2Fhtml%2Ftutorials%2Fmessaging_tutorial%2Ftask_pushclient.htm

Here's the Request details

```
URL :
        https://apnortheast.push.samsungosp.com:8088/spp/pns/api/push

Request Header :
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 302
    appID: APPID
    appSecret: APPSECRET

Request Body :
    {"regID":["04REGID"],"requestID":"REQUESTID","message":"badgeOption=INCREASE&badgeNumber=1&action=ALERT&alertMessage=1","appData":"{\"title\":\"\",\"description\":\"test\"}"}


Response :
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 162
    Connection: keep-alive

    {"results":[{"regID":"","requestID":"","statusCode":3052,"statusMsg":"error of application authentication failed - header: APPID, regId: 0000000000000000"}]}
```

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, We just remove the application on our device.
A new regId has been generated and this one works.

It's still a little bit weird cause it seems that sometimes the generated token doesn't work and I really don't know why.